# How can I run the command git pull within my Azure batch startup task?

Tags: git, bash, azure, azure-batch

When you add a new machine to a pool Azure batch allows you to specify a start up task to run on startup or restart of that node.

I would like to run `git pull` on my code repo so that each time a node starts it has the latest code.

To achieve this I have carried out the following:

1. Created a deploy key on the node image and added this deploy key to my git repo on bitbucket
2. Added the current copy of the git repo on the machine
3. Created a start task in Azure with the following command: `ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa; git -C /home/ubuntu/sourcecode/ pull'`
4. The start task is run as Task autouser, Admin

When the machine starts up the script runs but then I hit a problem in that it cannot verify the bitbucket host without user input and this causes the whole thing to fail.

I know that I need to update the known_hosts file somewhere but I don't know for which user or where?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, batch is doing what it should but, it seems like you are looking to verify the bitbucket host without user input and I think what you are aiming for is well documented here: `:)`

- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-set-up-ssh-public-key-authentication-so-that-I-can-use/qaq-p/171671

Essentially the attempt is to : `ssh public-key authentication so that you can use ssh, sftp or scp from users Bitbucket Pipelines pipeline`

With in node:

- you can `ls` into the `ls ~/.ssh`

Further to add:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics

With in : "Connecting to compute nodes" sub heading. Hope this helps.

Just an idea:

Further to add: I think you can make a shell script for the setup and run that as part of your start task and once that is done, you can enable git pull on the node.